# How to define alias dependent Drush extensions?

Tags: drush

I have a stage and an anonymized instance of a project both managed under the same user (www-data). The anonymized instance is taken from production instance and has a drush extension that can have a different version than the stage instance.

With one instance per user I can simply symlink the extension to the ~/.drush folder, but how would I do that with two different versions of the same extensions? Is there a way to define alias dependent extensions in Drush? If Drush does not support this, what would be a good OS work around?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of installing the drush extensions in a user specific scope within your user's profile, you can install them on a per-project (Drupal instance) base in your `{PROJECT_ROOT}/drush` folder.

Drush 9 checks for the existence of a `drush` folder one level above the Drupal web root.

This is easiest to manage by utilizing Composer for dependency management and adding a Drush installer path, Drush and any Drush extensions to the `composer.json` file. But of course you can also setup everything by hand.

Comment: Yes it is Drupal 7 and the first suggestion works for me! Thank you!